# bridging local application to website

Tags: javascript, dll, google-chrome-extension

I need a way to allow a user to open an application on their machine (example: Photoshop) via a button on my website.

More specifically... something to the effect of running via the command line.. c:\Photoshop\run.exe some args OR open /Applications/Photoshop.app some args

Understanding the risks, security issues this raises and seeing how javascript is unable to access the users local file system. To add this

Im starting to explore a way to perhaps have a DLL or browser extension dynamically add this trigger/button that will in turn open/execute this application. Where the user can install something locally to do this.

Im looking for a general idea of how I can achieve this... what combination of programming language.. protocol.. any hints...

Comment: You can simply register a URL protocol handler (`yourapp://whatever`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use registerProtocolHandler without contentWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900655/use-registerprotocolhandler-without-contentwindow)