# Use registerProtocolHandler without contentWindow

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

I'm trying to install hotmail to my mailto handlers:

[image]

This is accomplished with this code from webpage scope:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler('mailto','http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s','Live Mail');
```

From XPCOM we would have to use this: [MXR ::WebContentConverter.js#369)](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/src/WebContentConverter.js#369) .

So from searching github code I figure you import it like this:

```
var nsiwchr = Cc["@mozilla.org/embeddor.implemented/web-content-handler-registrar;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWebContentHandlerRegistrar);
```

So I would register it like this:

```
nsiwchr.registerProtocolHandler('mailto','http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s','Live Mail', null);
```

I use `null` because I don't have a `contentWindow` but apparently you can't pass null for this. Because:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/browser/components/feeds/src/WebContentConverter.js#372

```
var uri = this._checkAndGetURI(aURIString, aContentWindow);
```

And then it tests:

```
aContentWindow.location.hostname != uri.host)
```

So I figured to fake it out like this:

```
var fakeContentWindow = {
  document: {
    baseURIObject: {
      asciiHost:"mail.live.com",
      asciiSpec:"http://mail.live.com/secure",
      hasRef:true,
      host:"mail.live.com",
      hostPort:"mail.live.com",
      originCharset:"UTF-8",
      password:"",
      path:"/secure",
      port:-1,
      prePath:"http://mail.live.com",
      ref:"", //369
      scheme:"http",
      spec:"http://mail.live.com/secure",
      specIgnoringRef:"http://mail.live.com",
      userPass:"",
      username:""
    }
  },
  location: {
    hash:"", //#369
    host:"mail.live.com",
    hostname:"mail.live.com",
    href:"http://mail.live.com/secure",
    origin:"http://mxr.mozilla.org",
    pathname:"/secure",
    port:"",
    protocol:"http:",
    search:""
  }
};

nsiwchr.registerProtocolHandler('mailto','http://mail.live.com/secure/start?action=compose&to=%s','Live Mail', fakeContentWindow);
```

but it throws some totally weird error:

/*
Exception: [object XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper]
*/
Browser Console throws:

```
"[object XPCWrappedNative_NoHelper]" scratchpad.js:999
SP_writeAsErrorComment/<() scratchpad.js:999
Handler.prototype.process() Promise-backend.js:863
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop() Promise-backend.js:742
```

This makes no sense. I want to successfully spoof this without using a real `contentWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot use that high-level API without a window (and you probably don't want to use it anyway, because it will not actually add the handler, but show a UI notification that first asks the user to add it; which is not only not what you want, but also won't work because there is no UI to display that notification in the first place).

Instead, you'll want to create your own version based on the implementation that omits all those security checks, UI notifications, etc.

Based on `registerNotificiation`, it would look something like this.

```
var protocolScheme = "mailtoorsomething";
var uri = Services.io.newURI("someuri?with_%s_replacement", null, null);
var name = "Some Name";
var desc = "Some description";

var protocolHandler = Services.io.getProtocolHandler(protocolScheme);
if (!(protocolHandler instanceof Ci.nsIExternalProtocolHandler)) {
  throw new Error("Cannot register handler for built-in protocol");
}

var eps = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/external-protocol-service;1"].
          getService(Ci.nsIExternalProtocolService);
var handlerInfo = eps.getProtocolHandlerInfo(protocolScheme);
var handlers =  handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers;
for (let i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
  let h = handlers.queryElementAt(i, Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp);
  if (h.uriTemplate == uri.spec) {
    throw new Error("Already registered");
  }
}

var handler = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/web-handler-app;1"].
              createInstance(Ci.nsIWebHandlerApp);
handler.name = name;
handler.detailedDescription = desc;
handler.uriTemplate = uri.spec;
handlerInfo.possibleApplicationHandlers.appendElement(handler, false);

handlerInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling = false;
handlerInfo.preferredApplicationHandler = handler;
handlerInfo.preferredAction = Ci.nsIHandlerInfo.useHelperApp;

var hs = Cc["@mozilla.org/uriloader/handler-service;1"].
          getService(Ci.nsIHandlerService);
hs.store(handlerInfo);
```

Comment: This is cool. I see where you got it from. It was all there on that MXR page. Seting `hanlderInfo.alwaysAskBeforeHandling` to `true` differs from MXR's of `false`, but that's a good idea, I wouldn't have thought of that till it actually happend. Would similar components be involved in answering this question here: [Intercept/handle mime type/file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560243/intercept-handle-mime-type-file)? This struck me because of the word "Handler"

Comment: @Blagoh Missed that other question. Yes, it should be possible to create a handler for mime types as well. PDF.js does it.

Comment: Thanks man I should have been able to figure this out. The answer was lying right there. I was focusing on copying the wrong part. I noticed you skipped the test for "handled internally" and "if on black list"